# Agrupar las horas en su fecha correspondiente

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tengo una lista de datos en mi controlador de php, los cuales son los siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar *2022-08-01* está ocupando 6 horas.
¿Cómo puedo hacer que la fecha tenga sus horas ocupadas?
Ejemplo:

```
2022-08-01[
 hora_ini: "06:00:00"
 hora_ini: "10:00:00"
 "resto de las horas"
]
```

*Código*

Controller:

```
public function Agenda(){
    if($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('id_veterinarioinfo', 'id_veterinarioinfo', 'required');
      if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $id_vet = $this->input->post('id_veterinarioinfo', true);
        
        
        $valor = $this->cliente->Agenda($id_vet);
        
        $this->tools->outputJson($valor, 200);
      }
    }
  }
```

Modal:

```
public function Agenda($id_vet){
    $this->db->where("id_vetinfo=$id_vet and c.Activo = 1 and c.iEstatus < 1");
    $this->db->select("a.id_cita as id, a.fecha_cita as fecha, a.hora_ini");
    $this->db->from("agenda as a");
    $this->db->join("citas as c","c.iIdCita=a.id_cita");
    $get = $this->db->get()->result();
    return $get;
  }
```

Vista:

```
function seleccionarveterinarioinfo(id_veterinarioinfo) {
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?= base_url("Cliente_controller/Agenda")?>",
        data:{
            id_veterinarioinfo: id_veterinarioinfo
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR){
        console.log("fallo")
    })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas agrupar valores de una array por medio de una key, podrías usar una función que lo resuelva.

```
function agrupar($key, $data)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $val)) {
            $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
        } else {
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Luego solo le deberías pasar el array y la key por la cual quieres hacer el filtro para el agrupamiento.

```
$array = agrupar('fecha', $array);

echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

El resultado sería el siguiente. Lo imprimo en Json solo para la vista.

```
{
    "2022-07-20": [
        {
            "id": "134",
            "fecha": "2022-07-20",
            "hora_ini": "13:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "2022-07-23": [
        {
            "id": "139",
            "fecha": "2022-07-23",
            "hora_ini": "15:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "2022-08-01": [
        {
            "id": "140",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "06:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "141",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "10:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "142",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "07:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "143",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "08:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "144",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "09:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "145",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "11:00:00"
        },
        {
            "id": "146",
            "fecha": "2022-08-01",
            "hora_ini": "12:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "2022-07-25": [
        {
            "id": "147",
            "fecha": "2022-07-25",
            "hora_ini": "06:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, una duda la función la llamo en el controlador no ?

Comment: Si puedes llamarla desde el controlador.

Comment: Lo intente pero no funciono alfinal :/

Comment: No se como lo hiciste. Pero si el controlador lo usas para otras cosas no es recomendable que lo modifiques. Podrías crear uno nuevo y empezar a probar desde ahí. Envíame el código de lo que modificaste y lo vemos.

Comment: Ok en un momento amigo gracias

Comment: Listo de nuevo gracias por atender mi post

Comment: @AngelCab no edites la respuesta de otra persona para mostrar tu resultado final. En su lugar, redacta una nueva respuesta (en base a [answer]) y [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario ya lo edito, saludos.